# TypeError [CommandInteractionOptionType]: Option "user" is of type: 3; expected 6, 9

Tags: discord.js

I need target user this slashcommand discord
For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afnJ8.png)

But error console:

TypeError [CommandInteractionOptionType]: Option "target" is of type: 3; expected 9.

My code:

```
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("list-roles")
    .setDescription("Check user roles")
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
      .setName('target')
      .setDescription('Select a user')
      .setRequired(true)),

  run: async (client, interac`your text`tion) => {
    const user = interaction.options.getMentionable('target')
    let guildid = interaction.guild.id
    console.log(user)
  }
}
```

Change interaction.option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.addStringOption()` you can use `.addUserOption()` and can get the `User` by using `interaction.options.getUser('target')`

Here's the updated code:

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("list-roles")
    .setDescription("Check user roles")
    .addUserOption(option =>
      option
      .setName('target')
      .setDescription('Select a user')
      .setRequired(true)),

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')
    let guildid = interaction.guild.id
    console.log(user)
  }
}
```